# Zattoo App url scheme

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I need to open [Zattoo app](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/zattoo-tv-app-sports-news/id423779936?l=en) from my app (on a button click event)

what I have done is

```
let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "zattoo://")
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)

    } else {

        print("App not installed")

        //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Zattoo App installed

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/zattoo-tv-app-sports-news/id423779936?l=en")!)
   }
```

canOpenURL() always returns me the false (even Zattoo app is installed on my device) hence the code in else is executed always.

but if removing the check and just executing the

```
 let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "zattoo://")

 UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```

It's opening the the Zattoo app perfectly. Strange!

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS9 you should register custom schemes you want to use to open other apps. It should be stored as array of strings (custom schemes) with `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key in `Info.plist` file. From official documentation ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW14 ) :

> LSApplicationQueriesSchemes (Array - iOS) Specifies the URL schemes
>   you want the app to be able to use with the canOpenURL: method of the
>   UIApplication class. For each URL scheme you want your app to use with
>   the canOpenURL: method, add it as a string in this array. Read the
>   canOpenURL: method description for important information about
>   declaring supported schemes and using that method

There is an example how it can be used: https://github.com/gatzsche/LSApplicationQueriesSchemes-Working-Example

Comment: I have added zattoo:// in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. still I am getting the canOpenURL => false. the Problem is I can't install the zattoo app, its on the german app store, My account is on US app store. How can I test this. ?

Comment: Add url scheme whithout slashes - just zattoo. To download free apps from another countries try this trick - http://www.labnol.org/software/install-apps-from-itunes-store/13523/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "zattoo://") {
let canOpen = UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url)
```

}

Hope it helps.